# Rahmenprogramm nicht gefunden für Include ZR_PO_NUMBER_UC_INT

Tags: include, abap

I try to create an include according to the tutorial [SAP ABAP Include Programs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sap_abap/sap_abap_include_programs.htm). Unfortunately I get the message: Rahmenprogramm nicht gefunden für Include ZR_PO_NUMBER_UC_INT

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&  Include           ZR_PO_NUMBER_UC_INT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
PROGRAM ZR_PO_NUMBER_UC_INT.
CONDENSE i_PO_NUMBER_UC_1. e_PO_NUMBER_UC_INT =  i_PO_NUMBER_UC_1.
```

Comment: I'd suggest not to trust that tutorial. Having an introductory statement (https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abapprogram.htm) at the beginning of an include is not a good idea without further explanation, and having top-level code (i. e. anything but a class, a module or a subroutine) in an include is a bad idea as well.

Answer (score 2):

what you're missing is the main program, the report that `includes` your `Include`. In your tutorial this program is created in Step 5. So you need something like this:

```
REPORT Z_INCLUDINGTEST.

INCLUDE ZR_PO_NUMBER_UC_INT.

...
```